# How can i implement doPost() and doGet() request in the same servlet using ajax?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am doing a small project on jsp servlet.I want an example to implement doGet() and doPost()  methods using same servlet and sending and posting via an ajax call in forms in a jsp page.

Also specify why it is not recommendable to use doGet() and doPost() in the same servlet.How to implement the same using two different servlets but in the work in the same jsp page.

Thanks in advance any help would be benificial.

MY jsp code:-

```
 <form action="/mamababu.do" method="POST">
    <select name="command_no">
          <c:forEach var="items" items="${scriptItems}">

            <option value="${items.command}" name="command">${items.command}</option>

          </c:forEach>
       </select>
       <input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>
```

My servlet class:-

```
package com.project.mamabhagne;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.gson.Gson;


@WebServlet("/mamababu.do")
public class mamababu extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //get the data from database ie the model class
        try {
            List<Script> scriptitems=modelDBUtil.getScriptList();
           // String json = new Gson().toJson(scriptitems);

            request.setAttribute("scriptItems", scriptitems);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*String itemsfood[]={"biriyani","rice"};
        request.setAttribute("itemsfood",itemsfood)*/;



        //redirect to a different page
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher =request.getRequestDispatcher("scriptviewer.jsp");

        dispatcher.forward(request, response); 
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("hi");
         response.setContentType("text/html");
              PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
              out.println("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Hello World!</TITLE>"+
              "</HEAD><BODY>Hello World!</BODY></HTML>");
              out.close();
              RequestDispatcher dispatcher =request.getRequestDispatcher("scriptviewer.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response); 
    }


}
```

I am getting this error while posting form data:-

```
HTTP Status 404 - /mamababu.do


type Status report

message /mamababu.do

description The requested resource is not available.


Apache Tomcat/8.0.52
```

Comment: In your endpoint, you are redirecting using dispatcher servlet which not possible when using ajax, the redirection should be done in success handler of your ajax request.

Comment: i am here using jstl .you can clearly see in my jsp page .But the problem persists even if i remove the request dispatcher

Comment: `ending and posting via an ajax call in forms in a jsp page.` then why this sentence in your question.

Comment: ya i want that to be added but then also there is a problem in posting can you me an example servlet ajax post and get

Comment: If you want to implement ajax response should be in the form of plain text, JSON...etc

Comment: we can do it using gson library right

Comment: Yep, Use gson or jackson libs.

Comment: can you help me out how to call post using ajax

Comment: Plese refer https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/09/jquery-ajax-servlets-integration-building-a-complete-application.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear about your question, btw as my understand you need one servlet and response both GET and POST requests (via AJAX).

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyServelet", urlPatterns = {"/myservletForm"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {
    response.getWriter().println("Hello This is GET Response.");
  }
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException{
response.getWriter().println("Hello This is POST Response.");
}
}
```

as above when you send a 'get' request goes to doGet and 'post' request goes to doPost. You can choose need to invoke GET or POST by declaring particular ajax request type.

Comment: I have edited my question please have a look.And thank you for answering as it will be benificial.